# How to delete on cascade a self reference relationship?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cascading-deletes, self-referencing-table

I have a table that has a autoreference relationship, like that:

TableA(IDTableA, IDTableARoot,...)

and I have this instead of delete trigger to delete:

```
Delete from TableA where IDTableARoot IN(select deleted.IDTableA from deleted)
    Delete from TableA where IDTableA IN(select deleted.IDTableA from deleted)
```

I guess that I have this two rows:

Row 1:
IDTableA: 1
IDTableARoot: 1

Row 2:
IDTableA: 2
IDTableARoot: 1

When I try to delete the row 1:

```
delete from TableA where IDTableA = 1;
```

Only it is deleted the row with ID = 1, but not the row with ID = 2, but it shuld be deleted bacuse in the first statement of the trigger I say that I it has to be deleted the row with IDTableARoot = IDTableA where IDTableA is the ID of the row that I am deleting.

So, how could I delete in cascade rows that belong to a self relationship?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do another DELETE in a DELETE trigger which is disallowed as this can go into an infinite loop.

You might want to change your use a `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266401/delete-records-within-instead-of-delete-trigger)) and change your trigger body code to something like below

**UPDATED**: To address the error that @TT pointed out.

```
CREATE TABLE #CascadeDeleteRows (IDTableA int, IDTableARoot int)

INSERT 
  INTO #CascadeDeleteRows 
SELECT b.IDTable
     , b.IDTableARoot 
  FROM TableA
 WHERE b.IDTableA IN (SELECT deleted.IDTableARoot from deleted)

DELETE 
  FROM TableA 
 WHERE IDTableA IN (SELECT #CascadeDeleteRows.IDTableA FROM #CascadeDeleteRows)

DROP TABLE #CascadeDeleteRows
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @TT, thanks for pointing out, I have updated the answer.. hopefully this works